# Indexing edge sequences igraph - Special function and prefix form

Tags: r, functional-programming, igraph

I am currently developing a package relying on `igraph`. I want to access some edges by index.

So far I use special functions describe [here](https://igraph.org/r/doc/igraph-es-indexing.html), but R CMD is complaining because there is no visible global function definition such a `from()` and `to()`.

My code looks like :

```r
g <- graph.formula(foo1 -+ foo -+ bar1, foo -+ bar2)

E(g)[from("foo")]
```

Here I have access to all edges starting with `"foo"`. But now I want to access to the prefix form of this function. So I can access to the prefix function as:

```r
igraph:::`[.igraph.es`(g)
```

It's working, I have access to all edges, like if I did for a vector something like this:

```r
x <- seq.int(1,10)
`[`(x)
```

Then I try to access to the special function `from` as earlier like this

```r
igraph:::`[.igraph.es`(g, from, "foo")
```

I am sure I am not doing it right because I have this error message:

```
Error in eval(from) : object 'from' not found
```

How can I access to the prefix form of this special function?

Comment: @RonakShah I didn't think it was useful regarding the context of the question, `g` is really a dummy graph. But I've made the edit.

Comment: Not really an `igraph` expert but I can see that `E(g)` is of class `"igraph.es"` whereas `igraph:::\`[.igraph.es\`(g)` is of class `igraph`. So do you need `E(igraph:::\`[.igraph.es\`(g))[from("foo")]` ?

Comment: I've just tried your solution, but it doesn't work. R CMD is still issuing a note saying `no visible global function definition for ‘from’`.

Comment: it works for me in RStudio though.

Comment: You don't have the R CMD check issue or this is working? Because what you told me is working fine inside R Studio terminal, but when I check my package there is this note.